# how to compile objective c file in google native client?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, makefile, google-nativeclient

I have a npapi plugin(bundle) for chrome, which use C++ and objective-c. now it needs to be build by google native client.

I wonder that can nacl support objective-c? how to compile o-c file by MakeFile

And if possible, how to build nacl plugin in Xcode? I tried, but i found that the libraries of nacl are " archive with no architecture specification".(use lipo -info *.a)

I hope someone to help me, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: it uses obj-c? are you using Foundation.framework? if yes, that frameworks is not available(or at least not fully implemented) in other platforms, I doubt it will work. If not, what is the merit of using obj-c there?

Comment: BTW, Native client never mentions obj-c support. Only c/c++ https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/overview

Comment: Thank you for the comment ! My plugin now works with npapi on windows(dll) and mac(bundle) respectively, and mac plugin uses some frameworks. In order to least changes, at first I just want to modify npapi code to ppapi code. But I think it’s a wrong way, and I gave up finally…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Objective-C without any of its usual libraries then you should be able to use the PNaCl toolchain (which is based on LLVM) to have it parse Objective-C. I'm not aware of projects that have done this, so you should definitely [let folks on the mailing list know](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/native-client-discuss) if you get something working (do keep the questions on SO, though!).

It sounds like your application won't be running on the open web (where only architecture-independent PNaCl can run, not NaCl), so you could either [use the PNaCl toolchain](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/building) to create a `.pexe`, or you could use the same toolchain to create a `.nexe` for each architecture you target. The documentation I linked to helps with both approaches, but note that using the PNaCl toolchain to create a `.nexe` is [currently being improved](https://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/issues/detail?id=3946). You can therefore follow the instructions on the bug tracker, or try out nacl-clang when it's released (or build it yourself if you're brave).

Comment: Bastion, thanks for your answer. I gave up the way of including objective-c files to nacl plugin, and I am going to use c++ instead. I read the document(you link) before, but there are some confuses what I need to figure out by myself. Thanks again!